# how to copy the file that is on the server to the client in angular

Tags: angular, file

I have an excel file in my folder of angular (server), Which the user will download it in the selected folder by pressing a button.

I have no idea does i use this inside inside Controller, and not in the View.

I thought of using fs (filesystem), but when i require or import it, it does not get detected

Comment: `<a href="http://your.host/path/to/excelfile.xlsx">Download</a>`?

Comment: Thank you JB.. can I get from the server the directory where the download was made?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.